# sk-means clustering - how to get the cluster results

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, text-mining

I'm using both k-means and sk-means in my research. In K-means clustering, in order to get the clusters,

```
# k-means clustering of tweets
k<-6
kmeansResult<-kmeans(m3,k)

# Cluster centers
round(kmeansResult$centers,digits=3)

for(i in 1:k){
at(paste("cluster",i,":",sep=""))
s<-sort(kmeansResult$centers[i,],decreasing=T)
cat(names(s)[1:3],"\n")
}
```

And for sk-means clustering, I managed to get until

```
m3_new <- m3[slam::row_sums(m3) > 0, ]
skmeansResult<-skmeans(m3_new,k)
```

What is the next step I should do to get the cluster result?

Comment: @holzben Hi, referring to your earlier answer on [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21185336/clustering-how-to-extract-most-distinguishing-features, I try to do similar but I have some issues with the result I got, hope you can help me on that.

Answer (score 0):

```
km_clus <- kmeansResult$cluster

sk_clus <- skmeansResult$cluster
```