# Why is the cluster words' frequencies so small in a big dataset?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, text-mining

Referring to the question answered by @holzben [Clustering: how to extract most distinguishing features?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21185336/clustering-how-to-extract-most-distinguishing-features)

Using the SK-Means package, I managed to get the cluster. I couldn't figure out why the word frequency in all clusters is so small. It didn't make sense to me as I have about 10,000 tweets in my dataset. What am I doing wrong?

My dataset is available at https://docs.google.com/a/siswa.um.edu.my/file/d/0B3-xuXnLwF0yTHAzbE5KbTlQWWM/edit

```
> class(myCorpus)
[1] "VCorpus" "Corpus"  "list"   
> dtm<-DocumentTermMatrix(myCorpus,control=list(wordLengths=c(1,Inf)))
> class(dtm)
[1] "DocumentTermMatrix"    "simple_triplet_matrix"
> clus <- skmeans(dtm, 3)
> clus
A hard spherical k-means partition of 10829 objects into 3 classes.
Class sizes: 2100, 6219, 2510
Call: skmeans(x = dtm, k = 3)
> mfrq_words_per_cluster <- function(clus, dtm, first = 6, unique = TRUE){
+   if(!any(class(clus) == "skmeans")) return("clus must be an skmeans object")
+   
+   dtm <- as.simple_triplet_matrix(dtm)
+   indM <- table(names(clus$cluster), clus$cluster) == 1 # generate bool matrix
+   
+   hfun <- function(ind, dtm){ # help function, summing up words
+     if(is.null(dtm[ind, ]))  dtm[ind, ] else  col_sums(dtm[ind, ])
+   }
+   frqM <- apply(indM, 2, hfun, dtm = dtm)
+   
+   if(unique){
+     # eliminate word which occur in several clusters
+     frqM <- frqM[rowSums(frqM > 0) == 1, ] 
+   }
+   # export to list, order and take first x elements 
+   res <- lapply(1:ncol(frqM), function(i, mat, first)
+     head(sort(mat[, i], decreasing = TRUE), first),
+     mat = frqM, first = first)
+   
+   names(res) <- paste0("CLUSTER_", 1:ncol(frqM))
+   return(res)
+ }
> mfrq_words_per_cluster(clus, dtm)
$CLUSTER_1
  srilanka    warrior airtickets   avionics        ayf   citizens 
     4          4          3          3          3          3 

$CLUSTER_2
   higher     jumpa        ec     bodoh komentari     batch 
       12        11         9         8         8         7 

$CLUSTER_3
       liong      ryanair           yi airlinescrew         aksi      berjaya 
           5            4            4            3            3            3
```

and below is the script I used to get the above clusters:

```
require("tm")
require("skmeans")
require("slam")

clus <- skmeans(dtm, 3)

# clus: a skmeans object
# dtm: a Document Term Matrix
# first: eg. 10 most frequent words per cluster
# unique: if FALSE all words of the DTM will be used
#  if TRUE only cluster specific words will be used 
# result: List with words and frequency of words 
#         If unique = TRUE, only cluster specific words will be considered.
#         Words which occur in more than one cluster will be ignored.



mfrq_words_per_cluster <- function(clus, dtm, first = 6, unique = TRUE){
  if(!any(class(clus) == "skmeans")) return("clus must be an skmeans object")

  dtm <- as.simple_triplet_matrix(dtm)
  indM <- table(names(clus$cluster), clus$cluster) == 1 # generate bool matrix

  hfun <- function(ind, dtm){ # help function, summing up words
    if(is.null(dtm[ind, ]))  dtm[ind, ] else  col_sums(dtm[ind, ])
  }
  frqM <- apply(indM, 2, hfun, dtm = dtm)

  if(unique){
    # eliminate word which occur in several clusters
    frqM <- frqM[rowSums(frqM > 0) == 1, ] 
  }
  # export to list, order and take first x elements 
  res <- lapply(1:ncol(frqM), function(i, mat, first)
    head(sort(mat[, i], decreasing = TRUE), first),
    mat = frqM, first = first)

  names(res) <- paste0("CLUSTER_", 1:ncol(frqM))
  return(res)
}


mfrq_words_per_cluster(clus, dtm)
```

Comment: This question has no data set, leaves line characters in it for people who help to remove, and has no call to the packages you use.

Comment: My dataset is huge, can I know how to show the dataset? I am worried if I used subset of the data, it cannot point out my problem why the cluster showing those words that have least occurrence in the entire dataset. Please help

Comment: Use built in data sets.  Take part of your data set.  Something to make the problem minimal and reproducible.  Often this act alone has caused me to solve my own problems.

Comment: 10000 is not large. And with tweets, you usually have a lot of noise in there. Many won't even be english at all. Use e.g. `grep` to find out how many tweets really contain `srilanka` for example.

Comment: I have saved my dataset using dput() in a text file and uploaded onto Google Drive. Please help me!